# Chasing upvoted answered questions out my sight

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, questions

The 'unanswered' view is 'questions with no upvoted answers.' My recollection of a few months ago is this: if I upvoted an answer to a question, and clicked on 'Unanswered', that question would vanish PDQ.

Now, it seems to be taking much longer.

1. Is this real?
2. If it is real, is there anything I can to to restore a speedy departure?

Comment: PDQ? How quick was it then?

Comment: a minute or so.

Answer (score 2):

Shady car dealer says:  **That's real cache that you can take to the bank *today!***

More formally - the site is more aggressively cached now than it was months ago, and certainly more than it was when they started.  If it's taking hours to go away, please be more specific with your timeframes.  Otherwise it looks like a simple "The cache isn't fast enough for me!" problem, which is of relatively low priority.

Comment: OK, I'll break out the stopwatch.